# JQM, popup from link doesn't refresh select radio-choice-1 choice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

radio choice doesn't refresh?? Why doesn't it refresh it? When I refresh the page it does.

Here is my popup:

```
<a href="#popupMenuback" class='ui-btn-left' data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" >Done</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuback" data-overlay-theme="b" data-icon='check' data-dismissible="false" >
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:180px;" data-theme="c">
            <li data-icon='check'><a href="#popupSave" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window">Save</a></li>
            <li data-icon='delete'><a href="quote_details1.html?flag=changeProduct" data-inline="true">Discard</a></li> 
            <li><a href="" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Cancel</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

When I click on Discard I have a flip slider on that page:

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" name="deadline" id="deadline">

   <label for="radio-choice-1">Ongoing</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="ongoing"  />  <!-- checked="checked"-->

   <label for="radio-choice-2">Valid until</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="validuntil" />

</fieldset>
```

I change the different values on pagebeforeshow for quote_details1

```
$("#radio-choice-1").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Update:

I changed the name of the Id to a different name and It started working.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="ongoing"  />
```

To:  `<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="selectOngoing" value="ongoing"  />`

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="validuntil"  />
```

To  `<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="selectValid" value="validuntil"  />`

Comment: `.prop()` not `.attr()`.

Comment: Btw, I cant see any flipswitch in your code.

Comment: $(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(){ 
              
       var value=$("#deadline :radio:checked").val();
        
       if (value== "ongoing" ){ document.getElementById('date').style.display= 'none';};
       if (value== "validuntil" ){ document.getElementById('date').style.display='inline';};
       });

Comment: the .prop didn't solve it. It still does the same

Comment: `$("#deadline input:checked").val()`

Comment: Remains the same. It work only if I refresh the page.  $("#radio-choice-1").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");  Should do this, why doesn't it?

Comment: are you using _single page_ or _multi-page_ model? where are you place JS code?

Comment: single page, external js

Comment: Are you using Ajax to load pages? or is it off or are you using `rel="external"` to load other pages

Comment: Then each page should have JS in head.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48496/discussion-between-omar-and-user3023313)

Comment: It was the name issue. probably I had something similar in other pages..Thanks Omar.